# Displaying decimals in Java without trailing zeros

Tags: java

I came across this problem, I have a number of type long which represents time (only seconds and miliseconds). I would like to display it for example like this `1,124 ms`. I thought that simple division would do the job, so I tried this code

```
 long time = 2;
 System.out.println(((float) time) / 1000);
```

But when the number has only one digit like in the example above, it's giving me `0,0020`. So is there a way how to correct my formula or I have to manually cut the last zero?

Comment: This is a problem with formatting stuff for display, not a problem with division, so I've edited your question title...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a formatting statement that makes it 3 decimal places

```
String.format("%.3f", floatValue);
```

If you need to find out more about number formatting check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) link

Answer (score 0):

this will do the task

```
    long time = 2;
    float num = ((float) time) / 1000;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    String str = df.format(num);
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thank you but I think that Jon Taylors code solves it more nicely:)

Comment: It takes time before SO allows you to accept somebodys answer;-)